# Mejorar visibilidad de una salida

Tags: r

Hacemos un modelo de regresión para los datos mtcars.

```
mtcars
```

Quiero estimar mpg a partir del resto de variables:

```
m1<-lm(formula = mpg ~ . , data = mtcars )
```

Vemos cuales podrían ser las mejores variables para estimar mpg:

```
library(leaps)

mejores1 <- regsubsets(mpg~., data = mtcars, 
            nvmax = 10,
            nbest=1,
            method = "forward")


summary(mejores1)
```

- Para un modelo con una sola variable seleccionamos wt.
- Para un modelo con dos variables seleccionamos wt y cyl.
  etc.

Me gustaria pasar esta tabla

```
summary(mejores1)
```

a algo más visible,  como hay varios métodos para seleccionar variables
(method = "seqrep", "backward" ,"exhaustive")
es un lio compararlos, sobre todo cuando hay muchas variables. Me gustaría pasarlo a algo así

```
                    forward                        backward
1 variable            wt                              wt
2 variables       wt + cyl                        wt  + qsec 
3 variables       wt + cyl + hp                wt  + qsec +  am
```

o cualquier otra manera de ver los resultados de una forma más clara.

He probado con esto:

```
as.data.frame(summary(mejores1)$which) %>%
gather(key = variable, 
       value = variable_datos, -`(Intercept)`) -> datos

datos$`(Intercept)`<-NULL
datos %>% group_by(variable) -> datos
datos$posicion <- rep(seq(1,10),10)
datos[datos$variable_datos!="FALSE",] -> datos
datos$variable_datos<-NULL

datos$posicion<-ordered(datos$posicion, levels = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))


datos <- datos %>% group_by(variable) %>%
  summarise(posicion=min(posicion))

datos[order(datos$posicion),]
```

Te dice cual es la primera variable a escoger, cual es la sengunda etc,
pero seguro que hay mejor forma de hacerlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sé si es mucho mejor, pero ahí va:

Primero creo una lista con la selección de variables con cada método. Uso `lapply()` y el estilo nuevo de crear funciones lambda en `R` (>4.10). Se podría usar `map`.

```
métodos <- c("seqrep", "backward" ,"exhaustive")

lapply(métodos, 
       \(method) {
         regsubsets(mpg~., data = mtcars, 
                    nvmax = 3,
                    nbest=1,
                    method = method)
       }) |> 
  setNames(métodos) -> lista_mejores
```

Con `tidyverse`. La idea es crear tan pronto sea posible un dataframe y manejarlo así. Creo que es la opción más simple.

```
lista_mejores |> 
  map(~summary(.x)$which) |> 
  map(as_tibble) |> 
  bind_rows(.id = "método") |> 
  group_by(método) |> 
  mutate(variables = 1:n()) |>  #Acá sería mejor un rowsums para no depender de la posición.
  select(-`(Intercept)`) |> 
  pivot_longer(cols = cyl:carb) |> 
  filter(value) |> 
  select(-value) |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = método, 
              values_from = name, 
              values_fn = ~paste(., collapse = " + "))

# A tibble: 3 × 4
  variables seqrep        backward       exhaustive    
      <int> <chr>         <chr>          <chr>         
1         1 wt            wt             wt            
2         2 cyl + disp    wt + qsec      cyl + wt      
3         3 cyl + hp + wt wt + qsec + am wt + qsec + am
```

Con R base quizás se podría usar algo parecido a la aproximación anterior, acá hago lo mismo con pura manipulación de listas y funciones lambda. Es un poco más corto, pero innecesariamente complicado.

```
lapply(lista_mejores, \(x) summary(x)$which) |> 
  lapply(\(x) x[, -1]) |> 
  lapply(\(x) apply(x, 1, which)) |>  #Este apply anida la lista y complica todo lo que sigue.
  lapply(\(x) lapply(x, names)) |> 
  lapply(\(x) lapply(x, paste, collapse = " + ")) |> 
  lapply(unlist) |> 
  as.data.frame() |> 
  transform(variables = paste("variables", 1:length(seqrep)))
      
         seqrep       backward     exhaustive   variables
1            wt             wt             wt variables 1
2    cyl + disp      wt + qsec       cyl + wt variables 2
3 cyl + hp + wt wt + qsec + am wt + qsec + am variables 3
```

Comment: Pues no consigo actualizar R, estoy con la 3.6.3. A ver si lo consigo.

Comment: He conseguido actualizar a versión 4.1.3 (2022-03-10) y si pongo el código tal cual: Error in setNames(lapply(métodos, function(method) { : 
  objeto 'métodos' no encontrado

Comment: Omití agregar ese vector sobre el que se iteran los métodos. Edité la respuesta y ahora debería funcionar.

Comment: perfecto!!!!! No había visto antes esta nueva forma de hacer funciones.

Comment: Es relativamente nueva, en R 4.0 se implementó la tubería nativa `|>` que funciona muy similar a `%>%` y las funciones lambda `\(x)` en lugar de `function(x)`.  En R 4.20 se va a implementar el `_` para llamar explícitamente a los datos en el lado derecho de una tubería. Me gusta, soy usuario de `tidyverse`, pero a veces me frustro por las variaciones en las interfaces (los datos son `.` o `.x`, la función la declaro con `~` o en una lista) y el ciclo de vida muy corto de algunas funciones. Este "nuevo" R base me está gustando, sobre todo porque será más estable.